# Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'ReportsTo' at row 2

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

After creating Table when I am loading data from.csv file it is showing the error:

> "Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column
> 'ReportsTo' at row 2".

My csv file has null value in row 2. I have searched internet but i am not finding solution. I am using northwind data.

```
| EmployeeID | LastName  | FirstName | Title                    | TitleOfCourtesy | BirthDate | HireDate | Address                      | City     | Region | PostalCode | Country | HomePhone      | Extension | Notes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | ReportsTo | PhotoPath                              | Salary |
|------------|-----------|-----------|--------------------------|-----------------|-----------|----------|------------------------------|----------|--------|------------|---------|----------------|-----------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------|----------------------------------------|--------|
| 1          | Davolio   | Nancy     | Sales Representative     | Ms.             | 00:00.0   | 00:00.0  | 507 - 20th Ave. E.Apt. 2A    | Seattle  | WA     | 98122      | USA     | (206) 555-9857 | 5467      | Education includes a BA in psychology from Colorado State University in   1970.  She also completed "The Art   of the Cold Call."  Nancy is a   member of Toastmasters International.                                                                                  | 2         | http://accweb/emmployees/davolio.bmp   | 120000 |
| 2          | Fuller    | Andrew    | Vice President Sales     | Dr.             | 00:00.0   | 00:00.0  | 908 W. Capital Way           | Tacoma   | WA     | 98401      | USA     | (206) 555-9482 | 3457      | Andrew received his BTS commercial in 1974 and a Ph.D. in international   marketing from the University of Dallas in 1981.  He is fluent in French and Italian and   reads German.  He joined the company as   a sales representative was promoted to sales manager i  | NULL      | http://accweb/emmployees/fuller.bmp    | 200000 |
| 3          | Leverling | Janet     | Sales Representative     | Ms.             | 00:00.0   | 00:00.0  | 722 Moss Bay Blvd.           | Kirkland | WA     | 98033      | USA     | (206) 555-3412 | 3355      | Janet has a BS degree in chemistry from Boston College (1984).  She has also completed a certificate   program in food retailing management.    Janet was hired as a sales associate in 1991 and promoted to sales   representative in February 1992.                  | 2         | http://accweb/emmployees/leverling.bmp | 125000 |
| 4          | Peacock   | Margaret  | Sales Representative     | Mrs.            | 00:00.0   | 00:00.0  | 4110 Old Redmond Rd.         | Redmond  | WA     | 98052      | USA     | (206) 555-8122 | 5176      | Margaret holds a BA in English literature from Concordia College (1958)   and an MA from the American Institute of Culinary Arts (1966).  She was assigned to the London office   temporarily from July through November 1992.                                         | 2         | http://accweb/emmployees/peacock.bmp   | 100000 |
| 5          | Buchanan  | Steven    | Sales Manager            | Mr.             | 00:00.0   | 00:00.0  | 14 Garrett Hill              | London   | NULL   | SW1 8JR    | UK      | (71) 555-4848  | 3453      | Steven Buchanan graduated from St. Andrews University Scotland with a BSC   degree in 1976.  Upon joining the   company as a sales representative in 1992. he spent 6 months in an   orientation program at the Seattle office and then returned to his permanent   po | 2         | http://accweb/emmployees/buchanan.bmp  | 100000 |
| 6          | Suyama    | Michael   | Sales Representative     | Mr.             | 00:00.0   | 00:00.0  | Coventry HouseMiner Rd.      | London   | NULL   | EC2 7JR    | UK      | (71) 555-7773  | 428       | Michael is a graduate of Sussex University (MA economics 1983) and the   University of California at Los Angeles (MBA marketing 1986).  He has also taken the courses   "Multi-Cultural Selling" and "Time Management for the Sales   Professional."  He is fluent     | 5         | http://accweb/emmployees/davolio.bmp   | 140000 |
| 7          | King      | Robert    | Sales Representative     | Mr.             | 00:00.0   | 00:00.0  | Edgeham HollowWinchester Way | London   | NULL   | RG1 9SP    | UK      | (71) 555-5598  | 465       | Robert King served in the Peace Corps and traveled extensively before   completing his degree in English at the University of Michigan in 1992 the   year he joined the company.  After   completing a course entitled "Selling in Europe" he was transferred   to the | 5         | http://accweb/emmployees/davolio.bmp   | 240000 |
| 8          | Callahan  | Laura     | Inside Sales Coordinator | Ms.             | 00:00.0   | 00:00.0  | 4726 - 11th Ave. N.E.        | Seattle  | WA     | 98105      | USA     | (206) 555-1189 | 2344      | Laura received a BA in psychology from the University of Washington.  She has also completed a course in business   French.  She reads and writes French.                                                                                                              | 2         | http://accweb/emmployees/davolio.bmp   | 300000 |
| 9          | Dodsworth | Anne      | Sales Representative     | Ms.             | 00:00.0   | 00:00.0  | 7 Houndstooth Rd.            | London   | NULL   | WG2 7LT    | UK      | (71) 555-4444  | 452       | Anne has a BA degree in English from St. Lawrence College.  She is fluent in French and German.                                                                                                                                                                        | 5         | http://accweb/emmployees/davolio.bmp   | 220000 |
```

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
            EmployeeID INT(11),
            LastName VARCHAR(20),
            FirstName VARCHAR(10),
            Title VARCHAR(30),
            TitleOfCourtesy VARCHAR(25),
            BirthDate datetime,
            HireDate datetime,
            Address varchar(60),
            City varchar(15),
            Region varchar(15),
            PostalCode varchar(10),
            Country varchar(15),
            HomePhone varchar(24),
            Extension varchar(4),
            Notes MEDIUMTEXT,
            ReportsTo INT(11) NULL,
            PhotoPath VARCHAR(255),
            Salary FLOAT,
            PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID)
);

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/employees.csv'
INTO TABLE EmployeeS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Comment: Can you show us that row?

Comment: I've always found it easier to bulk load CSV data into a table where all fields are nullable VARCHAR, as a staging, and then insert it into the real tables as step 2, rather than try and wrestle with garbage within the bulk loading process..

Comment: You should read the section 'Handling of NULL values varies according to the FIELDS and LINES options in use:' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html and publish an example of a row you have a problem with.

Comment: Its written NULL at that row. @jarlh

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this even related to programming?

Comment: @jarlh I have added the column.

Comment: You need to add a FULL row(s) in case the error has crept in from another place in the csv file

Comment: I have tried many solutions from the internet. @Nico Haase

Comment: I have added the whole table @P.Salmon

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by edting it

Comment: But sadly not as a csv file so for me to treat that as a csv I'm going to have to edit it possibly correcting by by mistake..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you need special processing to handle the value.  You don't specify which value, but one method is to use variables.  So, if `salary` where the problem:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/employees.csv'
INTO TABLE EmployeeS (EmployeeId, LastName, . . . , @salary)
    SET salary = (CASE WHEN @salary <> 'NULL' THEN CAST(@salary AS FLOAT) END)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Of course, I have no idea what column is really the problem.  This is just an illustration of how to fix it.

That said, you might have other issues.  I would expect the data to line up with the columns in the table, and you might want to understand why they do not.

Comment: Did you mean “*if* `salary` is the problem”?

Comment: In .csv file there is NULL  in `ReportsTo` column. Tried this code not working. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: I think `salary` is not the problem. @Julia

Comment: @GHOSTRIDER, salary is _always_ a problem, either for the employee or for the company...

Answer (score 0):

This code worked.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/employees.csv'
INTO TABLE Employees
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```